# Error al generar dependencias de composer luego de clonar un proyecto

Tags: php, git, composer

Tengo un proyecto, el cual trabajo por medio de git para el control de versiones, estuve en la necesidad de clonar el proyecto, en otra computadora, y me saltó un error que decía:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\billetera-inicial2\vendor\composer/../myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/deep_copy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\billetera-inicial2\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\billetera-inicial2\vendor\composer/../myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/deep_copy.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\billetera-inicial2\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line` 66
```

hice un composer install para traer las dependencias, pero no funciona, me sigue apareciendo lo mismo, si alguien me puede indicar qué hacer, de verdad estaría muy agradecido.

PD: cuando hago el composer install, me aparece que se actualizó y genero el autoload

Comment: ¿Estás en la rama correcta? Cuando clonas un proyecto si no especificas nada, se hace checkout a la rama `master`.

Comment: Déjame ver qué si funciona

Comment: Acabé de mirar y si  estoy en la rama correcta, de hecho copié el repositorio principal junto con la carpeta de git, cuando abro la consola de git, me aparece la rama que corresponde, pero no funciona

Comment: ¿El otro ordenador donde te has llevado el proyecto tiene la misma estructura de directorios y ficheros, es decir, existe este fichero por ejemplo: `C:\xampp\htdocs\billetera-inicial2\vendor\composer/../myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/deep_copy.php` Si no es tema de rama incorrecta perece más bien problema de configuración de rutas en el xampp.

Comment: Cuando lo cloné, se supone que debe tener la esttructura del proyecto, pero lo que cambia es la estructura del vendor, el cual contiene las dependencias, justamente acabé de mirar , y la ruta que especificas, está en otra carpeta en vez de `vendor\composer` el `mylabs` está dentro de vendor